# Flutter ML kit vision doesn't detect faces

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-mlkit

In my project I use library `firebase_ml_vision 0.9.3+8` and now this library is not detecting faces.

My code which I use in project

Camera initialization:

```
CameraController _camera;
Detector _currentDetector = Detector.face;
CameraLensDirection _direction = CameraLensDirection.front;
final FaceDetector _faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(
      FaceDetectorOptions(enableLandmarks: true, enableContours: true));

Future<dynamic> Function(FirebaseVisionImage image) _getDetectionMethod() {
    return _faceDetector.processImage;
  }

Future<void> _initializeCamera() async {
    final CameraDescription description =
        await Facekeypoint.getCamera(_direction);
    _camera = CameraController(
      description,
      defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS
          ? ResolutionPreset.low
          : ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );
    await _camera.initialize();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));

    _camera.startImageStream((CameraImage image) {
      if (_isDetecting) return;

      _isDetecting = true;
      counter++;
      Facekeypoint.detect(
        image: image,
        detectInImage: _getDetectionMethod(),
        imageRotation: description.sensorOrientation,
      ).then(
        (dynamic results) {
          if (_currentDetector == null) return;
          setState(() {
            _scanResults = results;
          });
        },
      ).whenComplete(() => _isDetecting = false);
    });

    if (_camera != null && _camera.value.isInitialized) {
      fullHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
          (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * _camera.value.aspectRatio);
    } else {
      fullHeight = null;
    }
  }
```

FaceKeyPoint class:

```
class Facekeypoint {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('facekeypoint');

  static Future<String> get platformVersion async {
    final String version = await _channel.invokeMethod('getPlatformVersion');
    return version;
  }

  static Future<CameraDescription> getCamera(CameraLensDirection dir) async {
    return await availableCameras().then(
      (List<CameraDescription> cameras) => cameras.firstWhere(
        (CameraDescription camera) => camera.lensDirection == dir,
      ),
    );
  }

  static Future<dynamic> detect({
    @required CameraImage image,
    @required Future<dynamic> Function(FirebaseVisionImage image) detectInImage,
    @required int imageRotation,
  }) async {
    return detectInImage(
      FirebaseVisionImage.fromBytes(
        _concatenatePlanes(image.planes),
        _buildMetaData(image, _rotationIntToImageRotation(imageRotation)),
      ),
    );
  }

  static Uint8List _concatenatePlanes(List<Plane> planes) {
    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    for (Plane plane in planes) {
      allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
    }
    return allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  static FirebaseVisionImageMetadata _buildMetaData(
    CameraImage image,
    ImageRotation rotation,
  ) {
    return FirebaseVisionImageMetadata(
      rawFormat: image.format.raw,
      size: Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble()),
      rotation: rotation,
      planeData: image.planes.map(
        (Plane plane) {
          return FirebaseVisionImagePlaneMetadata(
            bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow,
            height: plane.height,
            width: plane.width,
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );
  }

  static ImageRotation _rotationIntToImageRotation(int rotation) {
    switch (rotation) {
      case 0:
        return ImageRotation.rotation0;
      case 90:
        return ImageRotation.rotation90;
      case 180:
        return ImageRotation.rotation180;
      default:
        assert(rotation == 270);
        return ImageRotation.rotation270;
    }
  }
}
```

Googling didn't help me.
Early I'm trying change library version (downgrade, upgrade) its not help me.
But `_scanResalts` always return empty list. Sorry for my English, can anyone help?

Comment: did you solve the issue? here facing the same

Comment: Same issue here, any update?

Comment: @kike Use ResolutionPreset.low for camera settings

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Answer:**
The camera framerate is highest on the low resolution, so, each frame will have less distortion in the plane, and hence faces will be quickly detectable.

If you wish to use the higher resolution, you might need to await for the face detection method for much longer because the phone/device will have to be stable for a clearer(less distorted) image to be taken and sent to the detector method.

*For Quick Detection:* Change set the `resolutionPreset` of the camera controller to `ResolutionPreset.low` for both android and IOS platforms.

```
_camera = CameraController(
          description,
          ResolutionPreset.low,
        );
```

**Long Answer: If you want to use ResolutionPreset greater than low**

You can also the preset ResolutionPreset.veryHigh.

```
_camera = CameraController(
              description,
              ResolutionPreset.veryHigh,
            );
```

But you need to give more time for the face-detection method to process. Use a `Future.microtask` for instance.

```
          final facesList = await Future.microtask(
            () => detect(
              image,
              handleDetection,
              description!.sensorOrientation,
            ),
          );
```

**Bonus** `firebase_ml_vision` is discontinued and deprecated in favour of [`google_ml_vission`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_vision).
You can update your entire project by swapping those two packages with minimal changes, as seen below.

Camera initialization:

```
CameraController _camera;
Detector _currentDetector = Detector.face;
CameraLensDirection _direction = CameraLensDirection.front;
final FaceDetector _faceDetector = GoogleVision.instance.faceDetector(
      FaceDetectorOptions(enableLandmarks: true, enableContours: true));

Future<dynamic> Function(GoogleVisionImage image) _getDetectionMethod() {
    return _faceDetector.processImage;
  }

Future<void> _initializeCamera() async {
    final CameraDescription description =
        await Facekeypoint.getCamera(_direction);
    _camera = CameraController(
      description,
      ResolutionPreset.low,
         
    );
    await _camera.initialize();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));

    _camera.startImageStream((CameraImage image) {
      if (_isDetecting) return;

      _isDetecting = true;
      counter++;
      Facekeypoint.detect(
        image: image,
        detectInImage: _getDetectionMethod(),
        imageRotation: description.sensorOrientation,
      ).then(
        (dynamic results) {
          if (_currentDetector == null) return;
          setState(() {
            _scanResults = results;
          });
        },
      ).whenComplete(() => _isDetecting = false);
    });

    if (_camera != null && _camera.value.isInitialized) {
      fullHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
          (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * _camera.value.aspectRatio);
    } else {
      fullHeight = null;
    }
  }
```

FaceKeyPoint class:

```
class Facekeypoint {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('facekeypoint');

  static Future<String> get platformVersion async {
    final String version = await _channel.invokeMethod('getPlatformVersion');
    return version;
  }

  static Future<CameraDescription> getCamera(CameraLensDirection dir) async {
    return await availableCameras().then(
      (List<CameraDescription> cameras) => cameras.firstWhere(
        (CameraDescription camera) => camera.lensDirection == dir,
      ),
    );
  }

  static Future<dynamic> detect({
    @required CameraImage image,
    @required Future<dynamic> Function(GoogleVisionImage image) detectInImage,
    @required int imageRotation,
  }) async {
    return detectInImage(
      GoogleeVisionImage.fromBytes(
        _concatenatePlanes(image.planes),
        _buildMetaData(image, _rotationIntToImageRotation(imageRotation)),
      ),
    );
  }

  static Uint8List _concatenatePlanes(List<Plane> planes) {
    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    for (Plane plane in planes) {
      allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
    }
    return allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  static GoogleVisionImageMetadata _buildMetaData(
    CameraImage image,
    ImageRotation rotation,
  ) {
    return GoogleVisionImageMetadata(
      rawFormat: image.format.raw,
      size: Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble()),
      rotation: rotation,
      planeData: image.planes.map(
        (Plane plane) {
          return GoogleVisionImagePlaneMetadata(
            bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow,
            height: plane.height,
            width: plane.width,
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );
  }

  static ImageRotation _rotationIntToImageRotation(int rotation) {
    switch (rotation) {
      case 0:
        return ImageRotation.rotation0;
      case 90:
        return ImageRotation.rotation90;
      case 180:
        return ImageRotation.rotation180;
      default:
        assert(rotation == 270);
        return ImageRotation.rotation270;
    }
  }
}
```